# Uniform distribution of points

Tags: algorithm, space

I have `m` points which I wish to uniformly distribute in `n`-dimensional space. By "uniformly" I mean that the all shortest-distance-pairs have similar values.

In other words, I would like the points to fill the space as evenly as possible.

Please, does anyone know how to achieve this? Does this problem have a name?

Edit:

For example, when I have 4 points and 2D plane then the coordinates should be [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, -1], [-1, 0]. Just a square. For 3D it's a cube. But I'm not sure what to do if there is different point count than 2^n.

Another way of thinking about it is to consider the points to be charged particles which repel each other. But it's very slow to run such simulation...

Comment: "Uniform distribution" is a [well established term with a very specific meaning](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformDistribution.html).

Comment: *"all shortest-distance-pairs have similar values"* and *"fill the space as evenly as possible"* are not the same thing.  For instance, evenly distributing the points on a line-segment fulfills the first.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: And also the second.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you might be interested in [low discrepancy sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence). These are used as a deterministic analog to the uniform distribution described in n.m.'s comment. They're often used in so-called "quasi-Monte Carlo" algorithms, where instead of sampling randomly one uses some kind of grid of points distributed more or less evenly over the domain.

Such sequences of points do not necessarily satisfy the condition you gave that "all shortest-distance-pairs have similar values," but I interpreted this more as an attempt at description rather than a hard requirement of the problem. If it's really important then this likely does not solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably want to look into [Sphere Packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing).

Comment: you would need to slowly increase the size of the spheres until exactly *m* fit.  it's not clear that the number of spheres that fit in a volume is continuous as the dimensions change, and it doesn't seem like it would be computationally efficient.  so i suspect there's a better approach (although it's not clear to me what it is).

Comment: If you can pack spheres then you can binary search on how many of a certain size fit in a box, it's clearly a monotonic function.

Comment: ah, sorry, i see your point - yes, you wouldn't need to "slowly increase".  but it's still expensive and discontinuous.

Answer (score 1):

here's another idea (it's not perfect, but i don't think anything here is, and you may need to choose based on details of your particular case): use  [binary space partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) ([more info here](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/graphics/bsptree-faq/)).

the general idea is that you take your n-dimensional space and split it into two using a (n-1)-dimensional surface.  then you split those two news spaces, and so on.  if you choose your surfaces carefully (so that they divide into approximately equal volumes and avoid funny shapes, for some some definition of funny) then you can see that this will be an approximation to what you're asking.

the main advantage of this approach is that it's typically very fast (it's used in video games and spatial simulations).  it's not going to be as fast (or as uniform) as low discrepancy sequences (which sound really cool) but i imagine it would work inside arbitrary convex hulls.